# How to get closest integer values in embedded c?

Tags: c

I am working in embedded c, variable x is a sensor data which is an integer (lies between 1 and 100) and i need to output a variable y on lcd as a linear relation of x but after rounding it to closest integer, will this code work? If not then what are other ways of doing the same.

```
int x
float y
int z
x=4 /*say its 4*/
y=((x*3.45)+3.5) /*which is a decimal*/
z=(unsigned int)(y)
```

Comment: You want to implement round(), floor() and ceiling()? For example, floor() gets integer part and you subtract that from real value and have a value, check if that is smaller than 0.5 then give floor otherwise give floor+1. Negatives included? floor() needs bittwiddling.

Comment: It would be very fast and easy to do this using fixed-point arithmetic, but since you have already accepted an answer I will assume that you don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int z = ((x * 3.45) + 3.5) + 0.5;  /* assuming x is non-negative */
```

Floating-point to integer is covered by implicit conversion, so you don't need to do it explicitly.  But the conversion is a truncate so the extra `+0.5` gets you to the actual closest integer.

Comment: What? I think you should add compiler warnings - I wouldn't ever use an implicit integer cast, it can cause the strangest of issues.

Comment: to be precise, `+0.5` is rounding to nearest, half away from 0 (in case x is positive).

Comment: There won't be any compiler warning since this is a standard implicit conversion.  It is well-defined that `"When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero)."`  It is only undefined `"If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type"`, but that's not a concern with the background of this question.

Comment: @mb84: You are right.  This is a `round half-away from zero`.  And it should be `-0.5` for negative values.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative suggestion:**

If your code is running on a fixed-point processor, then any floating-point operation is replaced by the compiler with a call to a library function (typically provided by the manufacturer, as part of the BSP).

In such case, you might want to avoid invoking floating-point operations within your code.

Create a hash table for all the values in the specified range (0-100):

```
int hash[101] =
{
      4,  7, 10, 14, 17, 21, 24, 28, 31, 35, 38, 41, 45, 48, 52, 55, 59, 62, 66, 69,
     73, 76, 79, 83, 86, 90, 93, 97,100,104,107,110,114,117,121,124,128,131,135,138,
    142,145,148,152,155,159,162,166,169,173,176,179,183,186,190,193,197,200,204,207,
    211,214,217,221,224,228,231,235,238,242,245,248,252,255,259,262,266,269,273,276,
    280,283,286,290,293,297,300,304,307,311,314,317,321,324,328,331,335,338,342,345,
    349
};
```

Then, simple use `y = hash[x]` for every given value of `x`.

Comment: This is a very good idea (as long as the problem remains constrained as presented).  Even if hardware floating-point is available, the operations are much slower than their integer counterparts.

Comment: Yep; It is really a matter of time/space tradeoff. If you can spare the memory space required for the hash table, then you can get your code running faster.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from @Joe Hass comment with an "after accepted" answer.

Skip *all* floating point math.
Scale the operation and round by adding 0.5 via 50u/100u.

```
int x;       // (lies between 1 and 100)
unsigned z;
#define A 345u /* 3.45 * 100 */
#define B 350u /* 3.5  * 100 */
// Do everything unsigned
z = ((unsigned) x * A + B + 50u)/100u
```

This does a  "rounding to nearest, half away from 0" (@mb84)
Note: A smaller scale of 20 could have been use, but 100 is clearer.